# URL auto parses slash to %2F on return Page()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url, razor

I have an issue when I return Page() in my app guys, and it is driving me crazy.

So I have my url as *https://localhost:1111/folder1/folder2/parameter*

When a handler is activated and I return Page(), the url changes to *.../parameter%2F*, which is a non-existent slash that gets parsed somehow. If this happens 2-3 times, the url gets larger and I get a **{The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence}**.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You should probably include code for an example "handler" that causes this.   (returning Page() shouldn't change anything in the url... )

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code?